# Not able to read s3 file with prefix in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am deploying the job on flink cluster. 
The S3 path is something like:

URL: s3a://bucket-name/pre/pre1/original/2019_12_19/file.parquet.gz

I am reading it as:

```
  val job = Job.getInstance
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(
          job,
          new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(url)
        )

        val hadoopInputFormat =
          new HadoopInputFormat(
            new AvroParquetInputFormat[GenericRecord],
            classOf[Void],
            classOf[GenericRecord],
            job
          )
        val data: List[tuple.Tuple2[Void, GenericRecord]] =
          env.createInput(hadoopInputFormat).collect().asScala.toList
```

And the job is not submitted though it is running file with sbt run.

Also when the job is deployed and the S3 URL is of type:

URL: s3a://bucket-name/2019_12_19/file.parquet.gz

It gets submitted successfully.

```
 val env: ExecutionEnvironment = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  env.setParallelism(parallelism)
```

Dependencies:

```
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.10.0" % "provided"
    "org.apache.flink" % "flink-s3-fs-hadoop" % "1.10.0"
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-hadoop-compatibility" % "1.10.0"
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % ""3.1.1""
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.2"
    "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.2.5"
    "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2.5"
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % "1.10.0" % "provided"

Exception:

    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Class class com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider does not implement AWSCredentialsProvider
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.createAWSCredentialProvider(S3AUtils.java:623)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.createAWSCredentialProviderSet(S3AUtils.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.DefaultS3ClientFactory.createS3Client(DefaultS3ClientFactory.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:256)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:477)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:274)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat.listStatus(ParquetInputFormat.java:349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:396)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat.getSplits(ParquetInputFormat.java:304)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopInputFormatBase.createInputSplits(HadoopInputFormatBase.java:159)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopInputFormatBase.createInputSplits(HadoopInputFormatBase.java:59)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.<init>(ExecutionJobVertex.java:257)



core-site.xml:




    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>fs.s3a.buffer.dir</name>
            <value>/tmp</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
            <value>iam</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
            <value>iam</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
            <value>https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>fs.s3a.path.style.access</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>
            <value>
                com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider,
                org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider,
                com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider
            </value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can You please share the exception that gets thrown ??

Comment: Added the exception please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Flink 1.10, it is only possible to use `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` as a [plugin](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/plugins.html).

You basically need to add the jar to your flink-dist as follows.

```
flink-dist
├── conf
├── lib
...
└── plugins
    └── s3
        └── flink-s3-fs-hadoop.jar
```

And also remove it from your fat-jar.